# Loader Appearing continue in ionic ios when login

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic development and I am facing some issue
We are consuming an API in the ionic3 app.
When the user enters the credentials for login whether they are valid or invalid it shows the message according to the results from API in android.
But When i enter the wrong credentials in the ios build it will continue shows the loader and not giving the API result.

Following the app.component

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Events, Nav, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
//import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/menu-controller';
import { StorageService } from '../pages/shared/storage.service';
import { ToastService } from '../pages/shared/toast.service';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { UserService } from '../pages/shared/user.service';
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav;

  alert: any;
  isAlertShown: boolean;

  task: any;
  rootPage: any = '';
  userDetails: any;
  showSubmenu: boolean = true; //for open always

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, 
    public menu: MenuController,
    private storage: StorageService, private toast: ToastService, public events: Events,
     private push: Push,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController, public network: Network, private api: UserService) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.userDetails = this.storage.getData('userDetails');
      this.isAlertShown = false;
      this.task = setInterval(() => {
        this.checkInternet();
      }, 3000);

      this.pushSetup();
      if (this.userDetails != undefined || this.userDetails != null) {
        this.rootPage = 'welcome';
      } else {
        this.rootPage = 'login';
      }

      this.initializeApp();
    });

    events.subscribe('user:login', (username) => {
      // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
      this.getLoggedIn();
    });

    events.subscribe('user:logout', () => {
      this.rootPage = 'login';
    });

    events.subscribe('root:change', (page) => {
      // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
      this.rootPage = page;
    });

    events.subscribe('user:pic', (userpic) => {
      // user and time are the same arguments passed in `events.publish(user, time)`
      this.userDetails = this.storage.getData('userDetails');
      this.userDetails = {
        userId: this.userDetails.userId,
        username: this.userDetails.username,
        profileUrl: userpic
      }
      this.storage.saveData('userDetails', this.userDetails);
      this.getLoggedPic('pic');
    });
  }

  initializeApp() { //for reduce time of white screen after splash
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      // do whatever you need to do here.
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      }, 100);
    });
  }

  checkInternet() {
    this.alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Disconnected',
      message: 'Please connect your device to internet',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Try again',
          handler: () => {
            this.checkagain();
          }
        }
      ], enableBackdropDismiss: false
    });
    this.api.getCategoryList()
      .then(result => {
        // console.clear();
        if (result.type == 'error') {
          if (this.isAlertShown == false) {
            this.alert.present();
            this.isAlertShown = true;
          }
          this.storage.saveData('connect', 'offline');
        }
        else if (result.status == true) {
          this.storage.saveData('connect', 'online');
          this.alert.dismiss();
        }
      })

    
  }

  public checkagain() {
    this.isAlertShown = false;
    //this.alert.dismiss();
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.storage.removeData('userDetails');
    this.toast.ShowNotification('Logout Successful', 'bottom');
    this.rootPage = 'login';
  }

  getLoggedPic(page) {
    this.userDetails = this.storage.getData('userDetails');
    if (page == "pic") {
      this.userDetails.profileUrl = this.userDetails.profileUrl + "?" + new Date().getTime();
    }
  }

  getLoggedIn() {
    this.userDetails = this.storage.getData('userDetails');
    if (this.userDetails != undefined || this.userDetails != null) {
      this.rootPage = 'welcome';
      this.userDetails = this.storage.getData('userDetails');
      this.userDetails.profileUrl = this.userDetails.profileUrl + "?" + new Date().getTime();
    } else {
      this.rootPage = 'login';
    }
  }

  openMenu(): void {
    //Commented for click on edit profile to not collepes
    //this.showSubmenu = !this.showSubmenu;
  }

  openPage(pagename: string) {
    this.rootPage = pagename;
    //this.nav.push(pagename);
  }

  openHomePage(pagename: string) {
    this.rootPage = pagename;
  }

  pushSetup() {
    console.log("inside pushSetup");
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: 'xxxxxxxxxxx
        forceShow: 'true'

      },
      ios: {
        alert: 'true',
        badge: true,
        sound: 'false'
      }
    };
    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => this.storage.saveData("token", registration.registrationId));

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));

  }
}
```

Following is my login.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, Events, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserLogin } from '../shared/user';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { ToastService } from '../shared/toast.service';
import { StorageService } from '../shared/storage.service';
import { MenuController } from 'ionic-angular/components/app/menu-controller';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage({
  name: 'login'
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {
  public loginForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean = false;
  public userDetails: any;
  private isUserLoggin: boolean = false;
  private devicetype: any;

  unamePattern = "(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})";

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder,public platform: Platform,
    private userService: UserService, private toast: ToastService, public loading: LoadingController, private storage: StorageService, private menuCtrl: MenuController,
    public events: Events) {

      if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.devicetype = "ios";
      }
      else {
        this.devicetype = "android";
      }
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false); // for sidemenu disable
    this.nav = nav;

    this.isUserLoggin = this.userService.isUserLoggedIn();

    this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }

  // get username() {
  //   return this.loginForm.get('username');
  // }

  public save(model: UserLogin, isValid: boolean) {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (isValid) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      debugger
      formData.append("user_login", model.username);
      formData.append("user_password", model.password);
      formData.append("device_type",this.devicetype);
      formData.append("device_id",""+this.storage.getData("token"));

    //  console.log("storage id of device ="+this.storage.getData("token"));
      let loader = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Please wait'
      });

      loader.present().then(() => {

      });
      //this.toast.ShowLoaderOnLoad();
      try {
        this.userService.loginUser(formData)
          .then(result => {
            loader.dismiss();
            if (result.status === true) {
              this.userDetails = {
                userId: result.data.user_id,
                username: result.data.first_name,
                profileUrl: result.data.picture_url
              }
              this.storage.saveData('userDetails', this.userDetails);
              this.events.publish('user:login', result.data.first_name); //send an event to menu for show name
              this.toast.ShowNotification(result.message, 'bottom');
              this.nav.setRoot('welcome');
            }
            else if (result.status === false) {
              this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                username: [model.username, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
                password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
              });
              this.submitted = false;
              this.toast.ShowNotification(result.message, 'bottom');
            }
            else {
              this.toast.ShowNotification('Something went wrong!', 'bottom');
              this.loginForm.reset();
              this.submitted = false;
              isValid = false;
            }
          })
      }
      catch (error) {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          username: [model.username, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
          password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        });
        this.submitted = false;
        this.toast.ShowNotification('Something went wrong!', 'bottom');
      }
    }
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    if (this.isUserLoggin) {
      this.nav.setRoot('welcome');
    }
  }

  public gotoregister() {
    this.nav.setRoot('register');
  }

  public gotoforget() {
    this.nav.setRoot('forget');
  }

  public resetForm() {
    this.submitted = false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your

```
loader.present().then(() => {

      });
```

is empty. Which means that your loader.dismiss() might activate before it is instantiated.

Try to put your try block in the call back of the present() function:

```
try {
        etc...}
```

Answer (score 0):

please Try with this

```
this.userService.loginUser(formData)
.then((res:any)=>{
  //Success Code here
  //Stop Loader 
}).catch((err:any)=>{
  //Error handling and Stop loader
})
```